# Python printing dictionary key and value divided by another variable

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I need to print a Dictionary showing the key and the value divided by another variable ... any suggestions the code I have tried is below

```
#Dim variables
total_votes = 0
candidate = {}
    

for row in csvreader:
    if row[2] in candidate.keys():
        candidate[row[2]] += 1
    else:
        candidate[row[2]] = 1
    total_votes += 1

for key, value  in candidate.items():
    percentage = int(value) / int(total_votes)
    print((key) + " v " + (percentage))      

    print(f"Tolal votes {total_votes}")
```

Comment: What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @mackorone I'm assuming because OP's combining a numerical and a string

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a string and a numerical together. There are a couple options.

Here's one:

```py
#Dim variables
total_votes = 0
candidate = {}
    

for row in csvreader:
    if row[2] in candidate.keys():
        candidate[row[2]] += 1
    else:
        candidate[row[2]] = 1
    total_votes += 1

for key, value  in candidate.items():
    percentage = int(value)/int(total_votes)
    # Using commas
    print(key, " v ", percentage)      

    print(f"Tolal votes {total_votes}")
```

I notice you've also used a f-string below. Two thoughts on this: f-strings only work on later versions of python3. If you're having an error here, it may be because of your version. Second, you can also use an f-string to print your key and value:

```py
print(f"{key} v {value}")
```

Assuming your dictionary is valid, this will work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried casing value and key as both int and float with